# Can you send outbound request from a VPS if all ports are closed?

Tags: http, port, vps

Suppose I have a VPS with private networking setup such that the only ports that are open are the port for SSHing into the server and the port that connects the server to other servers on the private network.  Can this same server still send requests through the internet and receive back responses?  If so, through what 'channel' are the requests/responses being sent/received?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the outbound firewall settings are on the server.  If the firewall allows all outbound connections then you can connect out to any server on any protocol.

However, depending on the hosting provider, they may limit the ports which you can use for outbound connections.  Most likely (but not guaranteed) you'll be able to use HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443).  It is quite possible that SSH (22) would be open as well.  Those three should cover most, if not all, of the needs to would have.